# how to use external camera with kinect sdk? i'm having complexity

Tags: wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using Background Removal **wpf** sample with **kinect**.

i want to get input from webcam **instead of** kinect camera.

what is the best method to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background removal with kinect is based on depth information provided by the kinect sensor. If you want to remove the background from  the images provided by a webcam, the depth information is not availble and a fundamentally different approach is required.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905346/removing-image-background-scene) to get an idea how this can be achieved.

Comment: thank you but i'm trying to use sensors, actually I want to implement augmented reality. how I can achieve this using c# or any other language?